# OrientDB 3.0.0 - OrientGraph

Tags: java, orientdb

trying to port my OrientDB application from v2 to v3 I get a lot of compiler errors telling me that classes I'm using such as e. g. OrientGraph cannot be found. In v2 these have been part of the orientdb-graphdb-2.2.29 package which is not included in the v3 distribution. Any idea, what to do?
Thanks in advance,
Mario

Comment: You should troubleshoot every exception and change your libraries accordingly, can you share a test case or even just the compiler errors?

Answer (score 1):

With OrientDB version 3.0 some things have changed:

- New database administration, access and pooling API: OrientDB 3.0 has a new API that is specifically intended to manipulate database instances (ie. creating and dropping databases, checking that a DB exists, creating single db connections and connection pools).
- Graph-document concepts unification in core API: In v 3.0 TinkerPop is just an alternative graph API. The main graph API provided by OrientDB is in the Core module
- New execution plan based query engine: OrientDB team completely re-wrote the SQL query engine. The new query engine is more strict, more accurate and explicit in the execution planning and of course faster!
- Support for query on remote transactions: Until V 2.2 remote connection did not allow to mix API operations and SQL statements in the same transaction. Version 3.0 finally solves this limitation, now you can mix SQL and API operations in a single, remote transaction and the tx isolation will be guaranteed by OrientDB, transparently.
- Support streaming of query result set: In V 3.0 we re-designed the binary protocol and the ResultSet API to support streaming on query result sets.

For more information on what's changed: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/release/3.0/What-is-new-in-OrientDB-3.0.html

Comment: Hi Michela, thanks for your reply. Is it right that it would be the best to remove all my 'com.tinkerpop.blueprints.*' dependencies and use the new core API? Is there any document available explaining how to do this? Or am I required to invest - again - a lot of hours and collect pieces of code from various sources? BTW: is there a TinkerPop capable version of OrientDB for Java 8+ available for download? If yes, can you provide a link? I've found none so far. Thanks in acvance